# AFNetworking Download Redirect

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am trying to download a file using AFNetworking and the download gets redirected to Amazons Web Services.  I can see the redirect but it never seems to pick up the download so I was wondering what I'm doing wrong!  Here's my code:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@?%@=%@", update.downloadUrl.absoluteString, @"auth_token", database.userAuthToken];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30.0];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setRedirectResponseBlock:^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", redirectResponse.debugDescription);
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", request.debugDescription);

    if(redirectResponse == nil) return request;

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:request.URL.absoluteString parameters:nil];
    return  urlRequest;
}];

[operation setOutputStream:[NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:[item.downloadUrl absoluteString] append:false]];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    [_currentItem setUpdateProgress:totalBytesRead / (float)totalBytesExpectedToRead];
    NSLog(@"BytesRead: %i, TotalBytesRead: %lld, BytesToRead: %lld", bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead);
}];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [self networkQueueComplete:operation withResponse:responseObject];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self networkQueueFailed:operation withError:error];
}];

[networkQueue addOperation:operation];
```

In the setRedirectResponse block I can see the right redirect url, but my setDownloadProgress block never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add a redirect page on my server,and run your code. I found that if return request directly in setRedirectResponseBlock:, the redirect download work well,setDownloadProgress block gets called.

```
[operation setRedirectResponseBlock:^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", redirectResponse.debugDescription);
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", request.debugDescription);
    return request;
}];
```

**UPDATE:**

My test redirect page:http://joiningsstest.byethost11.com/redirect.php
you can pass your redirect url with "url" parameter in http/get.

I’m not sure if your s3 url need authorize for access.In my test code,i used "http://still.s3.amazonaws.com/Material/Chimney/images/1.jpg" for redirect,this is a public s3 url.

Redirect page's code:

```
<?php
if($_GET['url'])
{
 header('HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Permanently');
 header('Location:'.$_GET['url']);
}
?>
```

My test code:

```
NSString * redirectURL = @"http://still.s3.amazonaws.com/Material/Chimney/images/1.jpg";
NSString * testURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://joiningsstest.byethost11.com/redirect.php?url=%@",redirectURL];
NSURLRequest * originalRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:testURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30.0];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:originalRequest];
[operation setRedirectResponseBlock:^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", redirectResponse.debugDescription);
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", request.debugDescription);
    return request;
}];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.jpg"];
[operation setOutputStream:[NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:false]];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    NSLog(@"BytesRead: %i, TotalBytesRead: %lld, BytesToRead: %lld", bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead);
}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me.  It's a 302 redirect to an Amazon S3 link and my `setDownloadProgressBlock` is just never called.

Comment: Gah!  I was setting the download location wrong!  Thank you for  your help!